# About what would it cost to run a few low traffic blogs on the new Amazon EC2 Micro Instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress

I'm thinking about ways to start a WP multisite a couple of blogs. It's going to start small, but hopefully grow over time.

First I was thinking about a VPS, but now I read about their cheap cloud computing.

I read they cost $0.02/h of CPU time, is that calculated for CPU usage, or just for every hour my server is on?

Do I need additional things to run Wordpress? Like storage and database stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically run wordpress on this.  You pay for every hour the server is on.  You would have to login and install Wordpress from scratch. You are getting a freshly installed system so you have to install the database, apache, copy wordpress in there, etc.  You won't get any sort of control panel like you would get with VPS.

Comment: Yes, reading your question again, if you just need wordpress, go for shared hosting.  If you really need a VPS, i would go with some cheaper VPS hosting.  Amazon EC2 is not stable enough

Answer (score 0):

IF you are new to hosting/wordpress you might want to look at a good shared hosting company such as SurpassHosting or something along those lines. You can install as many wordpress blogs as you want with a click of a button.

If you are comfortable installing a webserver, database server and installing wordpress then yes Amazon would work just fine.

With Amazon you pay per hour + bandwidth +storage if you get additonal storage (S3).

$!5 per month give or take for the cpu usage + bandwidth.